# Pandas column to row transform

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have my input dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X' : [1],
    'Y' : [2],
    'Z' : [3],
    'A_col1' : [10],
    'A_col2' : [20],
    'B_col1' : [100],
    'B_col2' : [200],
})
```

[image]

How do I convert it into the below format?

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X' : [1,1],
    'Y' : [2,2],
    'X' : [3,3],
    'Name' : ['A','B'],
    'col1' : [10,20],
    'col2' : [100,200]
})
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use `df1 = df.set_index(['X','Y', 'Z'])`
`df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)`
`df1 = df1.rename_axis(['Name',None], axis=1).stack(0).reset_index()`